# Strange Viewpager issue not coming full screen on tablets

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Viewpager on tablets don't come in full width even after I say match parent. They just show up half the screen.

I tried all ways to make it full width but doesn't show up at all. Can somebody guide me to solve this issue. Below are the details on how I have tried.

I have added xml file inside: layout-w600dp-land

```
     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/myviewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <com.ylg.others.ProgressWheel
                android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:matProg_barColor="@color/progressbar"
                app:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
    {

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return NumberOfPages;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
        {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
        {
            progressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            progress_wheel_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadingtext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());

            Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
                    .load(bannerItems.get(position).getbannerImage())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(imageView);

            LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            layout.addView(imageView);

            final int page = position;
            layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Page " + page + " clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }});

            container.addView(layout);

            return layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
        }

    }
```

And I am calling the mypager this was:

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
                        myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
                        viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

                        NumberOfPages = bannerItems.size();
                        myPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```